# Save a Site Collection As A Site Template (.stp) File

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, sharepoint-2007

I would like to be able to save a SharePoint 2007 site collection as a site template (.stp) file. Is this possible?

Thanks, MagicAndi

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you can do this by going to the site, selecting the Site Actions link, selecting Site Settings and then selecting the option "Save site as template". Or does that just save the site and not the site collection?

Comment: joeqwerty, this saves just the current site, and not the site collection.

Answer (score 1):

I work on the SharePoint team. I don't believe this is possible